# How to "clear" the plot when using streamed feedgnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to display a set of moving points.

I try using [feedgnuplot](https://github.com/dkogan/feedgnuplot) for this:

```
$ feedgnuplot --domain --stream trigger
1 2
2 3
3 4
replot
```

After that it shows 3 points. Now I want to update their position:

```
1.1 2.1
2 2.9
3.1 3.8
replot
```

I see new points, but old ones haven't gone...

Answer (score 0):

There's `clear` command, as mentioned in https://github.com/dkogan/feedgnuplot#special-data-commands .

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
replot
clear
1.1 2.1
2 2.9
3.1 3.8
replot
clear
```